# Calculate "moving" Covariance

Tags: algorithm, math, covariance

I've been trying to figure out how to efficiently calculate the covariance in a moving window, i.e. moving from a set of values (x[0], y[0])..(x[n-1], y[n-1]) to a new set of values (x[1], y[1])..(x[n], y[n]). In other words, the value (x[0], y[0]) gets replaces by the value (x[n], y[n]). For performance reasons I need to calculate the covariance incrementally in the sense that I'd like to express the new covariance Cov(x[1]..x[n], y[1]..y[n]) in terms of the previous covariance Cov(x[0]..x[n-1], y[0]..y[n-1]).

Starting off with the naive formula for covariance as described here:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance][1]

All I can come up with is:

```
Cov(x[1]..x[n], y[1]..y[n]) =
Cov(x[0]..x[n-1], y[0]..y[n-1]) +
(x[n]*y[n] - x[0]*y[0]) / n -
AVG(x[1]..x[n]) * AVG(y[1]..y[n]) +
AVG(x[0]..x[n-1]) * AVG(y[0]..y[n-1])
```

I'm sorry about the notation, I hope it's more or less clear what I'm trying to express.

However, I'm not sure if this is sufficiently numerically stable. Dealing with large values I might run into arithmetic overflows or other (for example cancellation) issues.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually that notation isn't clear at all. It looks as if you're trying to express the formula for covariance as a programming statement on a single line? The best solution would involve several statements and variables. Did you try implementing the other algorithms on the wikipedia page?

Comment: Well actually it's not a programming problem. My question is to which formula is suitable for calculating the covariance of the new "window" (1...n) based on the covariance of the previous "window" (0..n-1), i.e. without having to look at all the datapoints inbetween.

Comment: So assuming the datapoint "dropping out" is (x[0], y[0]) and the new data point is (x[n], y[n]) I've tried finding a formula that only requires the previous covariance, the old data point, the new data point, and the averages of the respective sequences...

Comment: The wikipedia page has an example algorithm under the heading *Online algorithm* that I think does just what you want.

Comment: Yes, the online algorithm is suitable for recalculating the covariance every time a new value pair (x[n], y[n]) is add. However, I'm not aware how to extend this to also removing the old value pair...

Comment: IIRC, the online algorithm has a corresponding operation for removing a value.  Have a look at Knuth's _The Art of Computer Programming_, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms.

Comment: You'll need to adapt it anyway, as Knuth evaluates variance, not covariance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying some form of "add the new value and subtract the old one".  You are correct to worry:  this method is not numerically stable.  Keeping sums this way is subject to drift, but the real killer is the fact that at *each step* you are subtracting a large number from another large number to get what is likely a very small number.

One improvement would be to maintain your sums (of `x_i`, `y_i`, and `x_i*y_i`) independently, and recompute the naive formula from them at each step.  Your running sums would still drift, and the naive formula is still numerically unstable, but at least you would only have *one step* of numerical instability.

A stable way to solve this problem would be to implement a formula for (stably) merging statistical sets, and evaluate your overall covariance using a merge tree.  Moving your window would update one of your leaves, requiring an update of each node from that leaf to the root.  For a window of size n, this method would take O(log n) time per update instead of the O(1) naive computation, but the result would be stable and accurate.  Also, if you don't need the statistics for each incremental step, you can update the tree once per each output sample instead of once per input sample.  If you have k input samples per output sample, this reduces the cost per input sample to O(1 + (log n)/k).

From the comments:  the wikipedia page you reference includes a section on Knuth's online algorithm, which *is* relatively stable, though still prone to drift.  You should be able to do something comparable for covariance; and resetting your computation every K*n samples should limit the drift at minimal cost.

Comment: You're right, the drift will most probably also be a problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no one has mentioned this, but you can use [the Welford online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm) which relies on the running mean:

The equations should look like:[image]

the online mean given by:
[image]

Comment: That would calculate the running covariance (ie. of all samples from the start). The question is looking for the moving covariance (ie. of the last N samples).